# HBase replication not working

Tags: hbase

I have two `HDFS` clusters with `HBase` on top of it, `cluster_1` and `cluster_2`.

On `cluster_1` (All nodes) I have edited the `hbase-site.xml` adding this:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.replication</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

And then in `cluster_1` I altered the table `foo` column family `bar` like this:

```
disable 'foo'
alter 'foo', NAME => 'bar', REPLICATION_SCOPE => 'my_peer'
enable 'foo'
```

Then created the peer `my_peer` like this:

```
add_peer 'my_peer', 'cluster_2-zookeeper:2181:/my_hbase_znode'
start_replication
```

No data from `foo` is replicated in `foo` table in `cluster_2`.

Am I missing anything? The `zk_dump` in `cluster_1` says that replication is enabled with peer `my_peer`.

*EDIT-1*

After adding the `hbase.replication=true` in `cluster_2`, I have been able to replicate tables where I am manually putting data with HBase shell. No luck with the others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table attribute `REPLCATION_SCOPE` is not set properly,

```
change from,
disable 'foo'
alter 'foo', NAME => 'bar', REPLICATION_SCOPE => 'my_peer'
enable 'foo'
```

to

```
disable 'foo'
alter 'foo', NAME => 'bar', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '1'
enable 'foo'
```

The attribute "`REPLICATION_SCOPE`" takes either `0` (replication=false) or `1` (replication=true).

Use the below command whether table is enabled for replication or not,
list_replicated_tables

Let me know if this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Please find the possible issues and their solutions
https://debugginghadoop.blogspot.com/2023/07/all-possible-hbase-replication-issues.html